# User property not available for notification

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics

With my app, I have a user property named "instance".
I have at least 10 values of this property and I can filter with it in dashboard view.

[image]

In firebase notification panel, I choose my app, then I click  "AND" to target a user property but the option is not available.

[image]

I have others apps with firebase and it works but here no. :(

Do you think because I have multiple flavors apps (myapp.dev, myapp.prod, myapp.preprod...) is the cause?

Do you have an idea please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

go to the right menu in firebase pannel. then select userPeroperies then click on create new peroperty. after doing that , thats must be enabaled

Comment: Thanks for this answer. For most languages, the "User Properties" panel is on the left side, not the right side. It's under Analytics > User Properties. From there, click "Add User Property" and add one of your user properties. That will enable User Properties in the A/B Test create UI.

Comment: @DoomGoober Can you guys post a screenshot because I can't see "User Properties" anywhere in the "Analytics" tab.